# What is CopyLibs in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, libraries

To add a library folder in an empty and newly created Java Application project in Netbeans I go to:

Right Click on Project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Browse

From the window opened I can choose a library folder.
In that process though a library called CopyLibs is inserted automatically by the Netbeans IDE.

What's its purpose and what does it do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CopyLibs folder contains the jar file org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask. It's a Netbeans own library and it's aim is to copy projects libraries in dist/lib folder during build process.